# Can someone explain how to implement newline handler fix for chat logging?

Tags: python

I really do not know how to explain this in the title. The problem is that I go for all the messages in text channel and populate it to the list, then I save it to the text file. Content of the message have the newlines due to formating in the chat client. Chat logger just saves all the messages with newlines thus harming the log file.

**CHAT CLIENT INPUT**

```
user1: who are the users on this server?
user2: oh that' easy my name is harry
       user3 is adam
       user4 is max
user1: okay got that
```

**BROKEN CHAT LOGGER OUTPUT**

```
12345 user1: who are the users on this server?
23456 user2: oh that' easy my name is harry
user3 is adam
user4 is max
12345 user1: okay got that
```

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**

```
12345 user1: who are the users on this server?
23456 user2: oh that' easy my name is harry
23456 user2: user3 is adam
23456 user2: user4 is max
12345 user1: okay got that
```

or

```
12345 user1: who are the users on this server?
23456 user2: oh that' easy my name is harry user3 is adam user4 is max
12345 user1: okay got that
```

Any tips how to implement such? I can do string.replace('\n', ' ') but I am more interested in the first approach that I suggested.

Comment: what is the "chat logger"? how would you tell when a user uses new lines for a reason?

Comment: I do not need a reason of why the user used a newline. I need to collect all the messages in the channel to train a neural network. Newlines are harming the learning ability of the neural network. Newlines should be splitted as new messages or contained in one string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a third option, using the `repr` version of strings in the log:

```
messages = [
    (12345, 'user1: who are the users on this server?'),
    (23456, '''user2: oh that' easy my name is harry
user3 is adam
user4 is max'''),
    (12345, 'user1: okay got that'),
    ]

for x, msg in messages:
    print(x, repr(msg))
```

Output:

```
12345 'user1: who are the users on this server?'
23456 "user2: oh that' easy my name is harry\nuser3 is adam\nuser4 is max"
12345 'user1: okay got that'
```

This saves you from having to implement special formatting like in your first example output, or losing information like in your second example output (newlines squished into spaces).